# NSButton tag ID returns inaccurate values past 7

Tags: macos, cocoa, osx-yosemite, appkit

I have a grid of 25 NSButtons. I'm attempting to set a tag on each of them, from 1-25, and link them to one IBAction, containing this:

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Clicked button %lo.", [sender tag]);
}
```

However, I'm running into a problem. It works fine from buttons 1-7, but the 8th one returns 10, the 9th returns 11, and the 10th returns 12. I experimentally set a button's tag to 88, and it returned 130. Is this a bug, or am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: Are you sure you have set tags correctly from `storyboard` or `xib` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your button values are correct, you're just printing them wrong, in octal format (the 'o' in %lo) instead of decimal. That's why your 8 prints out as a 10 -- that's 8 in octal representation. 130 is octal for 88 decimal:

Comment: I had totally forgotten about this question. But yes, looking back now that I have a few more years of experience, this is absolutely the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should use an `unsigned int` (**%u**) format, not `long` (**%lo**):

```
NSLog(@"Clicked button %u.", [sender tag]);
```

- depending on the format of your tag you could possibly just use `%o`. Treating the integer as long is what is adding to the number.